# jenkins pipeline script from SCM -> ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using jenkins as a dockerimage
I created a simple job with below git details:
i did add credentials from jenkins ui:-

```
url: https://myTeam:appPassword@bitbucket.org/MinoxTeam/bizcuit.git
credentials : myTeam /appPassword
```

this is working for simple job

I want to create a pipeline for jenkins and workwith jenkinsfile
I use the same git credentials for pipeline 
but error: cant fetch origin master.
error is :

```
stderr: remote: Invalid username or password
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://team:appPassword.git/'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://myTeam.myRepository.git
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:888)
```

my jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
      skipDefaultCheckout()
      }
        stages {
            stage(checkout) {
                steps {
                ws('/var/jenkins_home/workspace/pipelineDemo@script') {
                  git branch: 'feature/jenkinsTest',
                  credentialsId: 'appPassword',
                  url: 'https://myTeam:appPassword@bitbucket.org/myTeam/myRepository.git'

                sh "ls -lat"
                }
              }
            }
```

Comment: It looks like it doesn't like the team/password in the url - I would suggest you take them out. Also, I think credentialsId should have the id to the credentials configured in Jenkins, not the password.

Comment: @Joe I have generated a pipeline syntax for checkout step and it work from jenkins gui when i build pipeline script it works but the problem is with pipeline script from SCM does not work(error:credentials incorrect)

Answer (score 1):

`credentialsId: 'appPassword'` has to be the ID for the credentials and not the password itself.